# Click handler strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net

I am integrating a third party library "**Happiness meter**". I have implemented all the steps they mentioned but facing an issue regarding its initialization. The click handler sometimes works and sometimes not. Following are the steps:

1. I have added the script.
2. In its **data-mode** attribute of the script I've added **click** so it works only on click.
3. In data-mode-click-id I've added the ID "**happinessBtn**" of the button.
4. Before script tag I've added a div where it will render.
5. I've added the same ID "**happinessBtn**" to a different div because I want to open that meter on its click event.

Below is my code:

```html
<div id="happiness-meter-widget-container"></div>
<script id="happiness-meter-widget-script" src="https://happinessmeter.gov.ae/webwidget/services.js"
    data-container-id="happiness-meter-widget-container"
    data-language="@culture"
    data-key="development"
    data-on-finish="console.log(textStatus)"
    data-entity-sequence-id="112"
    data-main-service-sequence-id=""
    data-subservice-sequence-id=""
    data-subservice-complementary-id=""
    data-service-name-en=""
    data-service-name-ar=""
    data-customer-id=""
    data-email=""
    data-phone=""
    data-transaction-id=""
    data-emirates-id=""
    data-version="latest"
    data-delay="0"
    data-mode="click"
    data-mode-click-id="happinessBtn"
    data-css-url="CSS-URL">
</script>
<div class="icon" id="happinessBtn" data-placement="left">
    <i class="icon-happiness"></i>
</div>
$(document).on('click', '#happinessBtn', function () {

});
```

Note: when I use auto instead of click on **data-mode** attribute it starts working. Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: Why `css`, `asp.net` (`javascript`, `html`)?

Comment: @Andreas I am using all these techs in this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "**async**" keyword before script tag. e.g.

`<script id="happiness-meter-widget-script" async src="https://happinessmeter.gov.ae/webwidget/services.js"`

Adding this will make sure that the external script fetched in parallel to HTML parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available. For further details visit below link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two elements with the same id because id is unique for each page.

try to change the id to class and try again